# PHP - Replace items in a string with corresponding values from an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

I have a string e.g.

```
$str = "name is: ?, role is: ?";
```

and I have an array, e.g.

```
$array = array('John','Carpenter');
```

I want to replace each **?** in the string with the corresponding item in the array, i.e. the first **?** gets replaced with **John** and the second **?** gets replaced with **Carpenter**.

The number of values in the array will always be the same as the number of **?** in the string.

I have come up with the following code to do this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++) {
    $str = preg_replace('/\?/',$array[$i],$str,1);
}
```

My question is, is this the most efficient way of doing what I want to do? If you know of a method, or more efficient way of doing this, please could you post an answer?

Many thanks.

Comment: `$str = vsprintf(str_replace('?','%s',$str), $array);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [vsprintf](https://www.php.net/vsprintf) to do that:

```
$format = "name is: %s, role is: %s";
$array = array('John','Carpenter');

$str = vsprintf($format, $array);

echo $str;
// name is: John, role is: Carpenter
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback), which for each match calls a user-provided function that can return a different replacement each time:

```
$i = 0;
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\?/', function ($m) use ($arr, &$i) {
    return $arr[$i++];
}, $str);
```

Comment: perhaps a little overengineered for my purpose? seems the concensus is that vsprintf is what i need. thx for taking the time to answer.